# How Can I Make A 2-Column HTML5 Form?

Tags: html, forms, css, multiple-columns

I have a reservation form on my website, I own a limo company.

But in order to save space on my website I want to know how to make a 2 column form.

This is my form now:

```
            <form method="post" id="myForm" action="send2.php" class="sendmail" onsubmit="return validateForm()" style="text-align:center;">

        <h1 class="lead" align="center" style="font-size:35; font-weight:800">RESERVE TRIP</h1>


<ul li><h1 class="lead" align="center" style="color:black;font-weight:bold;list-style:none;">Contact Information</h1></ul li>

<ul li style="list-style:none">

    <li> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />





                        <p>

                            <table>

  <td><p><label>Full Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="name" style="margin:10px; width:285px; height:15px"></td>

  <td><p><label>Company Name:<input type="text" id="company" name="company" style="margin:10px; width:340px; height:15px"></label></p>

    </table> 

     <table align="center">

                <tr>

                    <td class="width:110px; height:15px">

                    <p><label>Phone #:<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="###-###-####" style="margin:10px; width:100px; height:15px">



                    </td>

                    <td class="width:70px; height:15px">

                    <p><label>E-mail:<input type="text" id="email" name="email" style="margin:10px; width:220px; height:15px">



                    </td>



                </tr>

                <tr>

                    </td>

                </tr>

                </table>



    </li>

</ul>

<ul li><h1 class="lead" align="center" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;list-style:none">Pick-Up Information</h1></ul li>





<ul li style="list-style:none">

    <li>


                <option selected="">--</option>

                                        <option>AM</option>

                                        <option>PM</option>

                                    </select></td>



                        </p>                       

            </table>






                    <table align="center">

                <tr>

                    <td class="width:110px; height:15px">

                        <label style="font-size:15px">Airport Name: <span class="error"></span></label>                                                             

                        <td class="width30">

                        <input type="text" id="rtairport" name="rtairport" class="input85" style="width:180px; margin:10px" value="">

                        </td>

                        </td>

                    <td class="width:110px; height:15px" align="center">

                        <label style="font-size:15px">Airline/Code:</label>                         

                        <td class="width30">                            

                <input type="text" id="rtairline" name="rtairline" class="input85" style="width:75px; margin:10px" value="">

                    </td>

                    </td>

                    <td class="width:70px; height:15px">                            

                    <label style="font-size:15px">Flight #:</label>

                    <td class="width30">

                    <input type="text" id="rtfnumber" name="rtfnumber" class="input85" style="width:40px;margin:10px" value="">

                    </td>

                    </td>   



                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>

                </tr>

                </td>

            </table>




        <br>


<li><h1 class="lead" align="center" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;list-style:none">Drop-Off Information</h1></li>

<ul li style="list-style:none">


        <center><p><label>Full Address:<input type="text" id="rtstreet" name="rtstreet" style="margin:10px; width:360px; height:15px"></label></p></center>

                    <table align="center">

                <tr>

                    <td class="width:110px; height:15px">

                        <label style="font-size:15px">Airport Name: <span class="error"></span></label>                                                             

                        <td class="width30">

                        <input type="text" id="doairport" name="doairport" class="input85" style="width:200px; margin:10px" value="">

                        </td>

                        </td>

                    <td class="width:110px; height:15px" align="center">

                        <label style="font-size:15px">Airline/Code:</label>                         

                        <td class="width30">                            

                <input type="text" id="doairline" name="doairline" class="input85" style="width:75px; margin:10px" value="">

                    </td>

                    </td>

                    <td class="width:70px; height:15px">                            

                    <label style="font-size:15px">Flight #:</label>

                    <td class="width30">

                    <input type="text" id="dofnumber" name="dofnumber" class="input85" style="width:40px;margin:10px" value="">

                    </td>



            </table>



</div>


</ul></li>
```

Any help/advice would help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put the form fields in two separate divs and float them left. Also make sure to set their widths and to make them fit next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Make two `<div>`s. These will be the two columns. Then, in their css, add `float: left`. If you need any more help, just ask.

Comment: Do I add float: left to the both <div>s?

Comment: No. Just the one you want on the left.

Answer (score 0):

What browsers do you need to support? If you're OK using semi-experimental CSS3 features that won't work in older browsers, just use [CSS3 columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts).

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you need some work with your tables

a general table format might look like

```
<form action="checkInput.php" method="POST">
<table border="1px solid #C00">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Table Heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>An Input for Column 1
            <input class="inputCSS" type="text" id="col1input" placeholder="Input Column 1" />
        </td>
        <td>An Input for Column 2
            <input class="inputCSS" type="text" id="col2input" placeholder="Input Column 2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Another row down for<br>Column 1</td><td>Another row down for<br>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

this example shows a title "Table Heading" and 3 rows by 2 columns. if you follow the pattern with the <tr> (table rows) and <td> (individual cells) you can expand on this 2 column format. Then you can tweak it to your preference. Also, keep the columns you want lined up in the same tables so the browser lines them up for you

once you start to understand how to type tables, a 2 column form won't be hard.